# Issues with SQL - INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    OrganizationName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Telephone VARCHAR(255),
    MobileTelephone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CustomerAdressLine1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CustomerAdressLine2 VARCHAR(255),
    PostalCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FederalTaxID VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    SageCustomerID BIGINT UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO Customer (OrganizationName, Telephone,  MobileTelephone, CustomerAdressLine1, CustomerAdressLine2, PostalCode, FederalTaxID, EmailAddress,  SageCustomerId) *
VALUES ('OrganizationName1', 'Telephone1', 'MobileTelephone1', 'CustomerAdressLine1', 'CustomerAdressLine2', 'PostalCode1', 'FederalTaxID1', 'EmailAddress1', 'SageCustomerId1'),
       ('OrganizationName2', 'Telephone2', 'MobileTelephone2', 'CustomerAdressLine2', 'CustomerAdressLine2', 'PostalCode2', 'FederalTaxID2', 'EmailAddress2', 'SageCustomerId2'),
       ('OrganizationName3', 'Telephone3', 'MobileTelephone3', 'CustomerAdressLine3', 'CustomerAdressLine3', 'PostalCode3', 'FederalTaxID3', 'EmailAddress3', 'SageCustomerId3');
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Where in my code is the error?

Comment: the error message is clear: you are trying to insert invalid characters into a `BIGINT` Field (integer type): `SageCustomerId`

Comment: On a different note. Address has 2 d's.

Comment: I would look closely at your datatypes also. Every string doesn't need to be 255. :D

Answer (score 4):

'SageCustomerId1' is not a valid BIGINT value.